# ios- Autolayout- add constraint respect to navigation item

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have just started to move my application to autolayout.
I want to give constraint to a label '0' pixel below navigation bar.
I tried but did not found solution.
Here are screen shots.

In storyboard I gave constraint from superview.

[image]

**In IOS7 it works fine.**

[image]

**But in IOS6 it goes below navigation bar by 64 pixels, as superview starts below navigation bar.**

[image]

If I could add top constraint for label below navigation bar it will solve the problem. But I cant find how to do it. I searched through few questions. but dint got the answer.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for iOS 11:**

iOS 11 introduces the concept of safe areas, and the burden of container all the content in a visible area is, again, at the hands of the view, rather than a tango of view and controller.

See Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).

When working with storyboards or XIBs, it's as simple as enabling the feature in Xcode. This is backward compatible and should work as expected under iOS 10 and below. In code, you would use `if (@available(iOS 11.0, *))` in order to decide whether to set constraints against the safe area guide/anchors or use the legacy guides on older systems.

---

When using storyboards, you need to add a constraint to the **top layout guide**. This will take care of your issues, as on iOS6, that is 0pt and on iOS7, it is dynamic. If you are using a nib/xib file, it gets a little more complicated; you need to add the constraint in code. The easiest way to achieve this is to create a constraint with 0 vertical space to top, create an outlet to this constraint in the code and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, update the `constant` of the constraint outlet to the value of `self.topLayoutGuide.length`.

Comment: Such a widely applicable tool to add to the tool-belt, and still valid nearly three years later. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make some modifications in your constraints :

1) Give a **height constraint** to your label

2) Pin your label to leading view - **Horizontal Space Constraint**

3) Add a **Vertical Space Constraint**

3rd step has to be careful [I'm attaching an image for your reference.]

[image: Adding Vertical Space Constraint]

And after doing that, check if the **red arrow mark** still persist on your View Controller.

Comment: Incorrect. If he adds a 0 vertical space, the label will go under the navigation bar.

Comment: Well, actually it was suggested by XCode itself on clicking the red arrow. And the Constraint seems to be working fine for me. Checked on both 7.0 and 6.

Comment: 0 works only if you disable extended edges and translucent bars.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are using storyboard. In that case, 0 is created not with top of view but top layout guide

Comment: Exactly :). I was wondering what 'd have made you think otherwise.

Comment: Not everyone uses storyboards. I have a feeling the OP does not, since his problem is typical with creating a constraint with the view's top instead of the controller's top layout guide.

Comment: But he has mentioned the use of storyboard in his question :)

Comment: why do you need to add the fixed height? completely unnecessary.